# How to prove rank(A+) is no more than rank(A)?

Tags: linear-algebra

look here my friend. How to prove the following equation? Or give a counter-example. Thank you so much

$$\text{rank}(A^+)\leq \text{rank}(A)$$

where $\text{rank}(A^+)$ represents the positive components of matrix $A$, e.g.
$$\left[\begin{matrix}2 & -1.5 & 0\\-2.3 & 2 & 4.1\end{matrix}\right]^+=\left[\begin{matrix}2 & 0 & 0\\0 & 2 & 4.1\end{matrix}\right].$$

Comment: This site is about the Mathematica software. For mathematical advice, please go to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Roman I don't that. Thank you for warm reminding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample is:

```
a = {{1, -1}, {-1, 1}};
aPlus = Clip[a, {0, Infinity}];
{MatrixRank[a], MatrixRank[aPlus]}
{1,2}
```

So a has rank less than the rank of aPlus. (Thanks to @Roman for generalization of aPlus.)

Comment: great example!!

Comment: Maybe use `aPlus = Clip[a, {0, Infinity}]` for more generality.